# uploading a file, renaming it and placing it in a particular location on server using Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

A user submits a file from a front end HTML form which has fields like Division, Department name, department number, section number, year, email, phone etc. The file being submitted might have a user given name. But, when it is uploaded I want it to be named as `Departmentname_departmentnumber_sectionnumber`.

So, if department is `Accounting`, dept number is `123` and section is `1`, name of file will be `Accounting_123_1.doc`. The extension will be whatever type of file (text, MS-Word's .doc or .docx, PDF or RTF) was submitted and the user can upload attachments of files with extension .txt, .doc, .docx, pdf, rtf only.

Also, I want it to be stored on a particular location on server. So, if Division is Corporate Finance and year is 2011-2012 it should be stored on server at `"E:\Files Submitted\2011-2012\Corporate Finance\"`. The `"E:\Files Submitted\"` part remains same in the directory name.

```
<cfset submittedfileName = #form.departmentname#&"_"&#form.departmentnumber#&"_"&#form.section_number_1#&"."&#cffile.ClientFileExt#>
<cfset filedirectoryYear = "E:\Files Submitted\"&#form.current_year#&"\"&#form.division#&"\">

<!--- ensure that the user uploads attachments of type with extension .txt, .doc, .docx, pdf, rtf only--->
<cfif FORM.attachment_1 neq "">          
  <cffile action="upload" 
    accept="text/plain,application/msword,application/pdf,application/rtf"        
    filefield="attachment_1"
    destination="E:\temp\uploads"
    nameconflict="Makeunique" 
  >

  <!--- rename the file and move it to permanent destination --->         
  <cffile action="rename" 
    source="E:\temp\uploads\#cffile.serverFileName#" 
    destination=#filedirectoryYear#&#submittedfileName#&#cffile.ClientFileExt#
  >

  <!--- now create a temporary variable for the attachment so that it can be emailed later on --->
  <cfset attachment_local_file_1 = #filedirectoryYear#&#submittedfileName#&#cffile.ClientFileExt#>            
</cfif>
```

I used the `cffile.ClientFileExt` because the files were getting uploaded without the extension but am receiving an error at   `destination=#filedirectoryYear#&#submittedfileName#&#cffile.ClientFileExt#` as

```
"multiple items at this position: Missing Token > or />
```

I am using Coldfusion 8. Any suggestions would be appreciated on where I am erring and how I can fix it.

Comment: FYI it is *not* necessary to enclose every variable in `##` everywhere in your code. This is perfectly fine: `<cfset filedirectoryYear = "E:\Files Submitted\" & form.current_year & "\" & form.division & "\">` and more readable, too.

Comment: Also, do not depend on mime type checks for security http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `&` in your code. Try this

```
<cffile 
  action="rename" 
  source="E:\temp\uploads\#cffile.serverFileName#" 
  destination="#filedirectoryYear##submittedfileName##cffile.ClientFileExt#"
>
```

String concatenation in ColdFusion either happens through variable interpolation

```
<cfset foo = "FixedString_#variable#_FixedString">
```

or as an expression

```
<cfset foo = "FixedString" & variable & "FixedString">
```

Do not confuse the two.